# Google Analytics: Unable to create more Property and View

Tags: google-analytics, page-views

I have 20 Properties and one of them has 10 Views. The "Create new Property" and "Create new view" are grayed out, after I added those 10 Views. Is there a limit or something I did wrong?

Comment: There isn't enough here to know what you are talking about. Is this a cms? A hosted web application?

Comment: sorry, its Google Analytics. I will add this to the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is for the API it may reflect limits imposed on general account usage.

Web Property Limits and Behavior

The following limits and behaviors are applicable to the Web Property resource:

There is an upper bound of 20 properties per account. Once this limit is reached, additional properties cannot be created through the API. However, existing properties can be updated and reused. See Limits and Quotas to learn about general limits.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtWebpropertyGuide